# Cannot get a close button to work on my expandable gallery

Tags: javascript

When I click the expandable image, a close button should appear to minimize the image again. The close button is not there.

HTML:

```
 <section class="container">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none'" class="closebtn">(&times;)</span>
        
        <img id="expandedImg" style="width: 100%">

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    color: #37647a;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

in order to reproduce the problem, just follow the link below and expand the image in the work [text](https://torysnopl.github.io/portfolio-page/#projects)section.

here is the repo with the full code:
[text](https://github.com/TorySnopl/portfolio-page)

I tried changing the css properties. Now I notice the live version the expandable menu doesnt work either.

let me know what I'm doing wrong:/

Answer (score 0):

Make the container relatively positioned so that the close button is positioned relative to the container.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```